# Transformation matrix of the derivative given the Legendre-basis for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

In the space of polynomials with degree $n\leq 3$ $V$ equipped with the inner product induced by $$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t$$ the accordingly normed Legendre polynomials $$\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}x,\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}(3x^2-1), \frac{\sqrt{14}}{4}(5x^3-3x)\right\}$$ form an orthonormal basis. As an exercise, I had to give the adjoint of the derivative $p\mapsto p'.$

So, I am currently trying to first get the Transformation matrix of the derivative according to the given basis, and then use transposition to find the adjoint.
However I have problems in expressing the image of the last listed basis vector, $\frac{14\sqrt{14}}{4}x^2-\frac{3\sqrt{14}}{4}$, in terms of only the third, $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}(3x^2-1)$, as they are not linearly dependent. I therefore think I made an error, as I can not get the typical diagonal in the transformation matrix, but i cannot find it.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Why must the transformation matrix be diagonal?

Comment: So that is the error? I was convinced that if there is an orthogonal basis there must be that diagonal and it also started out well; however, thinking about it, I had no basis to assume this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your calculations, it seems that all your diagonal entries should be $0$. That is, letting $\{e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ be the onb you gave above, you will find that the $i$th coefficient of $\frac{d}{dx} e_i$ expanded in that onb is zero.

For example:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left\{ \frac{\sqrt{14}}{4}(5x^3 - 3x) \right\} = \frac{5\sqrt{14}}{4}\left(3x^2 - \frac{3}{5}\right) = \frac{5\sqrt{14}}{4}\left(3x^2 - 1\right) + \frac{5\sqrt{14}}{4}\cdot \frac{2}{5} \\= a\, e_0 + b\, e_1 + c \, e_2 + k\, e_3
$$
has $a =  - \frac{\sqrt{14}/2}{1/\sqrt{2}}$, $b = 0$, $c = \frac{5\sqrt{14}/4}{\sqrt{10}/4}$ and $k = 0$.

Comment: I did not mean the diagonal of the matrix, I was referring to "that" diagonal that you often get for the derivative of polynomials, the one that is moved to the right by one place. However, you answered my question nonetheless. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to proceed is to apply a change of-basis to the matrix of the derivative operator relative to the standard basis, i.e., to the matrix $$D=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&3\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Letting $L$ be the matrix with the coefficients of the Legendre polynomials as its columns, we have $D'=L^{-1}DL$ relative to your basis. If you want to avoid direct matrix inversion and multiplication, you can compute this by row-reducing the augmented matrix $M=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}L&DL\end{array}\right]$, which will produce $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&L^{-1}DL\end{array}\right]$. The right side of $M$ consists of the coefficients of the derivatives of the Legendre polynomials, so you can avoid a matrix multiplication there, too, if you’re so inclined.

Comment: How to define the matrix L with Legendre  polynomials